# Why this JavaScript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mozilla

This is my code:

```
function habilitarsistemas() {
    if (document.getElementById("ChkSistemas").checked)
        document.getElementById("tabelasistemas").style.display = "block";
    else
        document.getElementById("tabelasistemas").style.display = "none";
}
```

It works fine with Firefox but it doesn't with IE and Chrome. Why?

Comment: Because it has errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery solution.

```
function habilitarsistemas() {
  if ($('#ChkSistemas').is(':checked')) {
    $('#tabelasistemas').css({ display: 'block' });
  }
  else {
    $('#tabelasistemas').css({ display: 'none' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain for @user3042318 why this code is better than his?

Comment: It has proper opening and closing and it's jQuery and I'm not saying it's better ;)

Comment: Tentei o script JQuery enviado pelo mdesdev porém não funcionou
vou postar a parte do código onde se encontra a tabel
Aparentemente ele não reconhece esse id.

   <table width="800" style="display: none;" id="tabelasistemas">

Comment: Obrigado a todos mas eu consegui apenas colocando as chaves nos ifs e elses
Por algum motivo ou não sei se o javascript tem isso apenas um linha no if é precisa ter a chave ¬¬ mas obrigado a todos!

Comment: Porque no meio, codificação feliz;)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to the HTML-tag providing only a @name attribute and not @id?
(There's a legacy mapping of @name to @id, but this is not supported in Chrome.)